# MongoDB UpdateMany with $in and upsert

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

Mongo collection named persons1 contains the following data:

```
db.persons1.find().pretty();


{ "_id" : "Sims",    "count" : 32 }
{ "_id" : "Autumn",  "count" : 35 }
{ "_id" : "Becker",  "count" : 35 }
{ "_id" : "Cecile",  "count" : 40 }
{ "_id" : "Poole",   "count" : 32 }
{ "_id" : "Nanette", "count" : 31 }
```

Now through Java I have written the code to increment the count for the users which are present in the list

```
MongoClient mongoclient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
MongoDatabase db = mongoclient.getDatabase("testdb1");
MongoCollection<Document> collection = db.getCollection("persons1");
List li = new ArrayList();
li.add("Sims");
li.add("Autumn");

collection.updateMany(
    in("_id",li),
    new Document("$inc", new Document("count", 1)),
    new UpdateOptions().upsert(true));
```

After I run the above java program my output was as below.

```
db.persons1.find().pretty();


{ "_id" : "Sims", "count" : 33 }
{ "_id" : "Autumn", "count" : 36 }
{ "_id" : "Becker", "count" : 35 }
{ "_id" : "Cecile", "count" : 40 }
{ "_id" : "Poole", "count" : 32 }
{ "_id" : "Nanette", "count" : 31 }
```

My question: Is it possible to Insert and start the count from 1, for the entry present in the Array list and not present in the persons1 Collection?

Problem Description:

Before Program database contains details as follows:

```
{ "_id" : "Sims",    "count" : 33 }
{ "_id" : "Autumn",  "count" : 36 }
{ "_id" : "Becker",  "count" : 35 }
{ "_id" : "Cecile",  "count" : 40 }
{ "_id" : "Poole",   "count" : 32 }
{ "_id" : "Nanette", "count" : 31 }
```

Sample Java code:

```
MongoClient mongoclient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
MongoDatabase db = mongoclient.getDatabase("testdb1");
MongoCollection<Document> collection = db.getCollection("persons1");
List li = new ArrayList();

// Entry already Present so required to increment by 1
li.add("Sims");

// Entry already Present so required to increment by 1
li.add("Autumn");

// Entry is NOT Present, hence insert into persons data base with "_id" as User1 and count as 1
li.add("User1");

// Entry is NOT Present, hence insert into persons data base with "_id" as User1 and count as 1
li.add("User2");

// Code to be written
```

What should be the code to get the out put from the database as shown below:

```
{ "_id" : "Sims",    "count" : 34 } // Entry already Present, incremented by 1
{ "_id" : "Autumn",  "count" : 37 } // Entry already Present, incremented by 1
{ "_id" : "Becker",  "count" : 35 }
{ "_id" : "Cecile",  "count" : 40 }
{ "_id" : "Poole",   "count" : 32 }
{ "_id" : "Nanette", "count" : 31 }
{ "_id" : "User1",   "count" : 1 }  // Entry Not Present, start by 1
{ "_id" : "User2",   "count" : 1 }  // Entry Not Present, start by 1
```

Comment: As far as I can see then the code you propose should do it correctly. So what is not working for you in the results?

Comment: My code will not insert the new id,as part of update i am including only increment operator..how to include id's list.So if it does not find id in the arraylist ,it will insert count as one,but id is being generated internally from mongo db.

Comment: This cannot possibly be true. 1. `_id` is "mandatory" and must be inserted always. 2. You do supply a list and the `.updateMany()` method "wraps" to imply "multi" as a param. As well you have "upsert". If you think you have different then please show the results to make this a reproducible case.

Comment: collection.updateMany(in("_id",li), new Document("$inc", new Document("count", 1).append("$set", new Document("_id", li))))
        , new UpdateOptions().upsert(true));

Comment: should the code be as above?

Comment: Aplologies. I eat my words after trying this and it fails. There is a solution though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "catch" here is that [`$in`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) arguments to `_id` will not be interpreted as a valid "filler" for the `_id` field within an "multi" flagged update, which is what you are doing. All the `_id` values will be populated by default `ObjectId` values instead on "upsert".

The way around this is to use "Bulk" operations, and with the Java 3.x driver you use the `BulkWrite` class and a construction like this:

```
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = db.getCollection("persons1");

    List li = new ArrayList();

    li.add("Sims");
    li.add("User2");

    List<WriteModel<Document>> updates = new ArrayList<WriteModel<Document>>();

    ListIterator listIterator = li.listIterator();

    while ( listIterator.hasNext() ) {
        updates.add(
            new UpdateOneModel<Document>(
                new Document("_id",listIterator.next()),
                new Document("$inc",new Document("count",1)),
                new UpdateOptions().upsert(true)
            )
        );
    }

    BulkWriteResult bulkWriteResult = collection.bulkWrite(updates);
```

That manipulates your basic `List` into [`UpdateOneModel`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/client/model/UpdateOneModel.html) objects with a list that is suitable for [`bulkWrite`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/async/client/MongoCollection.html#bulkWrite-java.util.List-com.mongodb.client.model.BulkWriteOptions-com.mongodb.async.SingleResultCallback-), and all "individual" updates are sent in the one request with the one response, even though they are "technically" mulitple update statements.

This is the only way that is valid to set multiple `_id` keys or matches via `$in` in general with update operations.

Comment: Facing this issue while executing the above code...Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Comment: @svsteja Sorry. Incorrect casting of a the `updates` object list. Bad habits and I did not check. Fixed.

Comment: @ Blakes Seven..Thank you..the above code worked..Is it possible to implement the same using spring data mongo

Comment: @svsteja If you have a different question then  [Ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Spring-mongo uses different operations to those introduced in the MongoDB 3.x Java driver, but the same bulk operations are still possible though either the earlier driver methods or just using spring-mongo update methods without bulk operations.